# Modify an excel file automatically with R

Tags: r, excel

**I have an excel data as follows:**

[image]

As you can see, the excel file contains 4 data entries `(month, X, Y , Z)` all of them are stacked in one column `(A)`. I am interested to create a program in `R` which can automatically separate the data from each other and finally generate a matrix that contains 4 columns (`month, X, Y , Z`) and three lines of their corresponding values. For example, the matrix

```
 M = [March, 12, 15, 44;

     April, 33, 34, 21;

     June, 44, 66, 33].
```

Else, is there any other solution (for example generate automatically a txt.file or a new excel file that can solve this problem and put all the data in one column each?

I have started writing the R code, but as I am new in R, so I am blocked. I am also not an Excel expert.

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: show the code that you have started?

Comment: @cory It is a mess trust me:p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It is a bit long but if will work for any elements you have. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions. The code loads the file. As the names are in the header you isolate in a vector for late process. With the data we use `separate_rows()` by `;` to split the row and then `pivot_wider()` to arrange again. Finally, we use `str_split()` to process the names. We assign them to data and export using `write.table()`:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Load
df <- read_excel('Libro1.xlsx',1,)
#Extract names
names(df)<-'V1'
#Reshape
input <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(V1,sep=';') %>%
  filter(V1!='') %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(id2=paste0('V',row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id2,values_from=V1) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-id)
#Separate
input <- input %>% separate(V1,c('Month','V1'),sep='-')
#Export
write.table(input,file='Myfile.txt',sep='\t',row.names = F)
```

In the `.txt` file you will have this:

```
  Month V1 V2 V3
1 March 12 15 44
2 April 33 34 21
3  June 44 66 33
```

Comment: Thank  you a lot. I tried your code, but it seems that when I generated the txt file, the values for X are stacked with the months. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't worry, but this code gives me an error: object 'X' not found

Comment: Always I get the same error: object 'X' not found :(

Comment: @Christina I have added a global change. Please re run all the new code and let me know if that works!

Comment: Thank you a lot! Live love Argentinaaa